Scroll not working after keyboard is open in compose
@Composable
fun IsKeyboardOpen(): State<Boolean> {
    val isImeVisible = WindowInsets.ime.getBottom(LocalDensity.current) > 0
    return rememberUpdatedState(isImeVisible)
}

so i  have this funtion and this in my main activity
  setContent {
            SampleAppTheme {
                MobileAppScreen()
            }
        }
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(android.R.id.content)){ view, insets ->
            val bottom = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime()).bottom
            view.updatePadding(bottom = bottom)
            insets
        }

now in my device what happening is when keybord is open i can scroll whole screen this is what i wanted . but same is not working in a lower android version let say android 8. is there anything which is not supported in lower versions. also i tried to get logs and in android 13 i saw i was getting logs whenever keyboard is opening and closing, but same was not happening in lowerviersion.
